# kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "login"

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to use a transition so that when selecting the "Log Out" button - the screen transitions to the left (giving the appearance of going from forwards to backwards).

This is for a help desk I am trying to design and I can't work out why its returning this error when I can perform this transition for other screens in my navbar.

I am new to Kivy and my code will probably upset anyone that views this in some way. Please go easy - but seriously any help is appreciated.

```py
from kivy import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationLayout, MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineAvatarListItem, ILeftBody
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList, Screen):
    pass


class NavLayout(MDNavigationLayout):
    pass


class Login(Screen):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class Nav(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    ScreenManager = ObjectProperty


class Homepage(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class AddNewCustomer(Screen):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class AddNewStaff(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    Login = ObjectProperty()


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Window.maximize()
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        # self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "900"
        login = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
        return login


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

```
ScreenManager:
    Login:
    Homepage:
    AddNewCustomer:
    Nav:
    DrawerList:

<Login>:
    name: "login"
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 700, 800
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Image:
            source: 'images/asteria.png'
            size: 100, 200

        MDLabel:
            id: login
            font_size: 40
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 15

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: user
            hint_text: "username"
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            hint_text: "password"
            icon_right: "eye-off"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            password: True

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "LOGIN"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "homepage"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "CLEAR"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: app.clear()


        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50


<Nav>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Add New Customer"

                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewCustomer"
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "right"





            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Add New Staff"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewStaff"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Case List"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "caseList"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Log Out"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.screen_manager.current = "login"









<Homepage>:
    name: "homepage"
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                title: 'Navigation'
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                right_action_items: [["images/asteria.png", lambda x: None]]


                elevation:5
            Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            Nav:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer


        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: "Homepage"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Welcome Home"
                        halign: "center"


                Screen:
                    name: "addNewCustomer"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New customer"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "addNewStaff"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New Staff"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "caseList"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case List"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "casePool"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Pool"
                        halign: "center"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two screen_managers, you need to refer to the one containing the `<Login>` Screen. So simply change the `.kv` file:

This line in `<Nav>`:

```
OneLineListItem:
    text: "Log Out"
    font_size: 15
    halign: "center"
    on_release:
        root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
        root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"
        root.manager.current = "login"
```

And this line in `<Hompage>`:

```
MDNavigationDrawer:
    id: nav_drawer
    Nav:
        screen_manager: screen_manager
        nav_drawer: nav_drawer
        manager: root.manager
```

Full `.kv` file:

```
ScreenManager:
    Login:
    Homepage:
    AddNewCustomer:
    Nav:
    DrawerList:

<Login>:
    name: "login"
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 700, 800
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Image:
            source: 'images/asteria.png'
            size: 100, 200

        MDLabel:
            id: login
            font_size: 40
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 15

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: user
            hint_text: "username"
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            hint_text: "password"
            icon_right: "eye-off"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            password: True

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "LOGIN"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "homepage"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "CLEAR"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: app.clear()


        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50


<Nav>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Add New Customer"

                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewCustomer"
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "right"





            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Add New Staff"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewStaff"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Case List"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "caseList"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Log Out"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.current = "login"


<Homepage>:
    name: "homepage"
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                title: 'Navigation'
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                right_action_items: [["images/asteria.png", lambda x: None]]


                elevation:5
            Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            Nav:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
                manager: root.manager


        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: "Homepage"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Welcome Home"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "addNewCustomer"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New customer"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "addNewStaff"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New Staff"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "caseList"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case List"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "casePool"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Pool"
                        halign: "center"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help - I no longer get the error message, but it doesn't do the transition. I checked this and regardless of whether i put "left" "right" "up" "down" etc. It always does the same transition of going right like my other left transitions (i.e. going forward) putting "right" for this specific part of the nav seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry about that, change `root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"`  to `root.manager.transition.direction = "left"` for the log out button. I edited the answer to include it. If this answer helped you please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.